# Columna condicional evaluada por filas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo un dtaframe de la siguiente forma:

```
Df = pd.DataFrame({'TIPOIDPRESTADOR': ['CC', 'NI', 'CE', 'RS'],
                                'Levels': [0, 1, np.nan, np.nan]
                      })
```

| TIPOIDPRESTADOR | Levels |
| --- | --- |
| CC | 0 |
| NI | 1 |
| CE | NaN |
| RS | NaN |

y Quiero ejecutar un bucle que dado el valor maximo de la columna 'levels' (en este caso 1) evalúe en cada fila si el valor es NaN, y en caso de ser verdadero asigne el valor máximo mas 1, actualice el valor máximo y continue con el ciclo hasta recorrer todas las filas

La salida deseada sería algo así:

```
Desired_Output = pd.DataFrame({'TIPOIDPRESTADOR': ['CC', 'NI', 'CE', 'RS'],
                                'Levels': [0, 1, 2, 3]
                      })
```

| TIPOIDPRESTADOR | Levels |
| --- | --- |
| CC | 0 |
| NI | 1 |
| CE | 2 |
| RS | 3 |

Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma:

```
for row in Df.iterrows():
    Max_value = float(max(Df[["TIPOIDPRESTADOR"]))
    Df['TIPOIDPRESTADOR'] = np.where(Df["TIPOIDPRESTADOR"].isna()==True, Max_value+1,  Df["TIPOIDPRESTADOR"])
    Max_value = Max_value+1
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente resultado:

| TIPOIDPRESTADOR | Levels |
| --- | --- |
| CC | 0 |
| NI | 1 |
| CE | 2 |
| RS | 2 |

Aparentemente es una tarea fácil pero me está costado mucho.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Buen día, utilizar ciclos no es lo mejor para resolverlo, se puede hacer con funciones propias de `pandas`, revisa la respuesta que te dejé.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable **no** utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Una forma de hacerlo utilizando funciones propias de `pandas` es primero identificar todos los valores que son `NaN` utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) y podemos saber el "número de ocurrencia" de los `NaN` utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html). Es decir, cada vez que se encuentre un `NaN` va a sumar `1`, por lo que la siguiente línea de código:

```
print(df['Levels'].isna().cumsum())
```

Devuelve la siguiente serie:

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
Name: Levels, dtype: int32
```

Con estos valores lo único que hace falta es sumarle el valor máximo de la columna, que se puede obtener con [`pandas.Series.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html). A los valores que son `NaN` que se les puede asignar el valor máximo actual con [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'TIPOIDPRESTADOR': ['CC', 'NI', 'CE', 'RS'],
                                'Levels': [0, 1, np.nan, np.nan]
                      })
df['Levels'] = df['Levels'].isna().cumsum() + df['Levels'].fillna(df['Levels'].max())
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
  TIPOIDPRESTADOR  Levels
0              CC     0.0
1              NI     1.0
2              CE     2.0
3              RS     3.0
```

### Edición

Había un error en la forma de calcular los valores que van a rellenar los `NaN`, tanto el `cumsum` como `max` deben ir adentro de `fillna`

Ejemplo actualizado:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'TIPOIDPRESTADOR': ['CC', 'NI', 'CE', 'RS', 'FF', 'AA'],
                                'Levels': [0, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan]
                      })
df['Levels'] = df['Levels'].fillna(df['Levels'].isna().cumsum() + df['Levels'].max())
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
  TIPOIDPRESTADOR  Levels
0              CC     0.0
1              NI     1.0
2              CE     2.0
3              RS     3.0
4              FF     1.0
5              AA     4.0
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias!

Comment: No funciona en caso de los nulos no estén todos al final y estén alternados p.e : [None, 1, None, None]
                      })

Comment: Gracias @Francisco, ya he editado la respuesta y corregido el problema.

Answer (score 1):

El calculo del valor máximo debe estar fuera del bucle for, además de que tiene errores sintácticos y que lo debes hacer sobre la columna numérica :

1. `Max_value = float(max(Df["Levels"]))`

Prueba con algo así, recorriendo cada tupla e incrementando el max solo si hay un cambio:

```
for row in Df.itertuples():
 if not Df.at[row.Index,'Levels']<= Max_value:
    Df.at[row.Index,'Levels'] =  Max_value+1
    Max_value = Max_value+1
    
print(Df)
```

2. Output:

```
  TIPOIDPRESTADOR  Levels
0              CC     0.0
1              NI     1.0
2              CE     2.0
3              RS     3.0
```

Una solución compacta y casi imposible de entender:

```
Df['Levels'].where(~pandas.isna(Df['Levels']),Df["Levels"].max()+pandas.isna(Df['Levels']).cumsum(),True)
```

Comment: Al trabajar con `dataframes` los ciclos deben ser siempre la última opción. Las funciones de `pandas` se han diseñado para trabajar rápida y eficientemente con los `datafraames`, procura dejar los ciclos como última opción.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, estuve pensando luego la mejor solución y no la encontré...